# Jquery: Click event doesn't work after append. (Don't know how to use .ON)

Tags: jquery, append

I have 2 click events. One appends an IMG which includes another click event. It doesn't work obviously. I know that I have to use jQuery's .ON, but I just can't figure out how and where.

My code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // The one below (.choimh) isn't triggered anymore
    $('.choimg').click(function(){

    });

    // Switch to chosen color
    $('.color').click(function(){
        $(".thumbs").append('<a href="#"><img id="image'+u+'" class="choimg" src="/img/products/mini/'+colnumber+'-'+ i + '.jpg" />');
    });
});
```

The .color div is on a completely different place than .choimg.

I just can't figure out how to use .ON.

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) help?

Comment: Put `.on()` on existing parent element that is already in the DOM, however, you can also use `document` or `body`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It used to be the `live` or `delegate` functions that did this kind of thing. Now you can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.choimg', function(e) {

//do whatever

});
```

Comment: Instead of "document", better to put an element that contains 'choimg':

Comment: Thank you! A lot of time looking for the answer!

Answer (score 13):

[jQuery's on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) does a lot, but for your specific case, you want to put "on" onto a DOM object that is not loaded up after the DOM has loaded. This allows the event to bubble up to this DOM object which, then, in turn, delegates the event to the appropriate DOM item based on the second selector your provide.

If you follow the link above, there is a ton of information about it in the jQuery documentation. Specifically, this is important for your case...

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.

In any case, you need to bind to the thing that already exists, and provide a second selector for the thing that is going to be added that you want to have the actual event, along with the event, and the functionality. Something like this...

```
$('#selector-to-thing-that-exists').on('click', '.thing-that-will-be-added-later', function() {
  alert('Do stuff here!');
});
```

Note that it is important that the "thing that exists" is as low as you can possibly get it in the DOM for efficiency. For example, it is not preferable to put the selector on the 'body' or at the document level. Keep this in mind.

Hopefully this gives a bit of a better understanding for what you want to do. I *highly* encourage you to read the jQuery documentation as it is very good.

Comment: Thank you, the "thing that exist" was the bit that I was missing.

Answer (score 5):

You should use something like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".color", function() {
//append code here
});
```

General prototype is `on(eventType, selector, function)`, you can use other events too.

For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).