# Ajax: refresh div continuously with onclick jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have been trying refresh the div contents after button click but it happen only one time and need to refresh the page to click the button again to refresh the content. I'm new to AJAX, please help me to solve this issue.

Here is my HTML:

```
<li id="personal-info" class="personal-info-wrapper">
    <div class="profile_content" id="personal-info-contents"> 
      **more codes to follow....**
      **at last**
    <tr class="pro-info-set">
        <td class="info-group-left">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="js_personal_title" name="js_personal_title">
        </td>
        <td class="info-group form-inline">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="js_personal_desc" name="js_personal_desc">
            <input id="submit_person" class="form-control" type="button" value="Add">
            <label id="submit_person_msg" value="Add"></label>
        </td>                                       
    </tr>
       <?php }  ?>
</table>
```

Here is my JS

```
$("#submit_person").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    js_personal_title = $("#js_personal_title").val();
    js_personal_desc= $("#js_personal_desc").val();
    if (js_personal_title !== null && js_personal_title !== "") {
        if (js_personal_desc !== null && js_personal_desc !== "") {
            var datastr = 'js_personal_title='+js_personal_title + '&js_personal_desc='+js_personal_desc; 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/Jobseeker/add_personal' ?>",
                data: datastr,
                success:function(e) {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    $(".personal-info-wrapper").load(location.href  + " #personal-info-contents");
                }
            });
        } else { alert('Please enter the decription');}
    } else { alert('Please enter the title');}
return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you checked the Ajax response. Is **success** callback called ?

Comment: yeah, its working, when I try second time only its getting stuck

Comment: did you assigned the **$("#submit_person").click(** on Document Ready event ?

Comment: yeah its surrounded with that, I just skipped it here

Comment: check out browser console window for Javascript errors on the second click.

Comment: Nothing is howing there its like freezing the button

Comment: Is this markup accurate? Your whole form is inside the `li` element?

Comment: Yeah, but there is no form though, its execute one time per page loads

Comment: Possibly, this post will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196185/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-after-append-dont-know-how-to-use-on

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing out all the elements inside the `li` element and replacing them with new ones. Your old listeners are gone. You'll have to reattach the listeners or use delegation. For example, change this:

```
 $("#submit_person").click(function(e){
```

For this:

```
 $('.personal-info-wrapper').on('click','#submit_person', function(e) {
```

This assuming `.personal-info-wrapper` never gets replaced.

Comment: Cool, this solves lots of questions I have, thanks a lot.